repetir un input dentro de un foreach
Tengo un codigo que muestra el nombre, la fecha de nacimiento y otros valores mas que son datos guardados en la BD, la edad la calcula tomando el valor de la fecha de nacimiento y la muestra con la ayudad del script en años y meses tal como lo muestro en el codigo.
El problema se presenta debido a las iteraciones dentro del foreach, cuando solo es un valor no hay problema, y me muestra la edad pero solo aparece el valor de la edad en la primera iteracion ya que si tengo mas de 2 datos guardados se queda en blanco el input de edad.
Espero puedan ayudarme


<script>
       
        //Calcular edad
        const fechaNacElement = document.getElementById("dateOfBirth");
        const ageInput = document.getElementById("age");


        let fechaNacText = fechaNacElement.textContent.trim();
        console.log("Fecha original:", fechaNacText);

        let partesFecha = fechaNacText.split(/[-/]/);
        let dateOfBirth;

        if (partesFecha.length === 3) {            
            if (partesFecha[0].length === 2) {
                dateOfBirth = new Date(partesFecha[2], partesFecha[1] - 1, partesFecha[0]);
            }            
            else {
                dateOfBirth = new Date(partesFecha[0], partesFecha[1] - 1, partesFecha[2]);
            }
        }

        console.log("Fecha parseada:", dateOfBirth); // Para debugging

        if (dateOfBirth && !isNaN(dateOfBirth.getTime())) {
            calculateAge(dateOfBirth);
        } else {
            ageInput.value = "Fecha inválida";
        }

        function calculateAge(dateOfBirth) {
            const today = new Date();
            const ageInMilliseconds = today.getTime() - dateOfBirth.getTime();
            const ageInYears = Math.floor(ageInMilliseconds / 31536000000);
            const ageInMonths = Math.floor((ageInMilliseconds % 31536000000) / 2629800000);

            if (ageInYears === 0) {
                ageInput.value = ageInMonths === 0 ? `Días de nacido` :
                    ageInMonths === 1 ? `${ageInMonths} mes` :
                        `${ageInMonths} meses`;
            } else {
                const yearString = ageInYears === 1 ? `${ageInYears} año` : `${ageInYears} años`;
                const monthString = ageInMonths === 0 ? `` :
                    ageInMonths === 1 ? ` y ${ageInMonths} mes` :
                        ` y ${ageInMonths} meses`;
                ageInput.value = yearString + monthString;
            }
        }
       

    </script>
<div class="container">
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <div class="card gradient-card2 mb-3">
            <div class="card-body">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4 position-relative">
                        <div class="d-flex flex-column align-items-center text-center mt-5">                            
                            <div class="mt-3">
                                <h4>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Nombre)</h4>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-8">                        
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-3">
                                <h6 class="mb-0">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Raza)</h6>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-6 text-secondary">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Raza.Descripcion)</div>
                        </div>
                        <hr />
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-3">
                                <h6 class="mb-0">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Edad)</h6>
                            </div>                            
                            <div class="col-sm-6 text-secondary" hidden><span id="dateOfBirth">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FechaNac)</span></div>
                            <div class="col-sm-6 text-secondary"><input class="form-control" id="age" /></div>
                        </div>
                        <hr />
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-3">
                                <h6 class="mb-0">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Color)</h6>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-6 text-secondary">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Color)</div>
                        </div>                                    
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
    
</div>




No puedes usar id porque debe de ser unico.  Utiliza clases.

como te dijo alan, si vos iteras 3 elementos vas a estar renderizando 3 elementos con el mismo id, y eso va a hacer que tu codigo falle. No tengo idea de asp pero sospecho que si tomas todo tu script y lo convertis en una unica funcion que reciba la fecha de nacimiento por parametro y retorne la edad, solo tendrias que hacer algo como @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => funcionParaCalcularEdad(item.FechaNac))

El problema en tu código es que estás usando el mismo id para los campos dateOfBirth y age. En HTML, el id es como un nombre exclusivo: cada id debe ser único en la página.
Cuando el foreach crea varios elementos con el mismo id, Js solo considerará el primero e ignorará los demás.
Al usar document.getElementById("age"), solo se tomará en cuenta el primer campo de edad y dejará los otros en blanco.
Usando getElementById se seleccionará únicamente el primer elemento encontrado.
Una solución es usar el atributo class, que puede tener nombres repetidos en lugar de ids.
Error ocurrido:
<div class="container">
    <div class="card">
        <h4 id="name">Item 1</h4> <!-- ID duplicado -->
        <span id="dateOfBirth">2020-01-01</span> <!-- ID duplicado -->
        <input id="age" />
    </div>
    <div class="card">
        <h4 id="name">Item 2</h4> <!-- ID duplicado -->
        <span id="dateOfBirth">2021-02-02</span> <!-- ID duplicado -->
        <input id="age" />
    </div>
</div>

Cómo podría ser:
<div class="container">
    <div class="card">
        <h4 class="name">Item 1</h4> <!-- Correcto: Usando class -->
        <span class="dateOfBirth">2020-01-01</span> <!-- Correcto: Usando class -->
        <input class="age" />
    </div>
    <div class="card">
        <h4 class="name">Item 2</h4> <!-- Correcto: Usando class -->
        <span class="dateOfBirth">2021-02-02</span> <!-- Correcto: Usando class -->
        <input class="age" />
    </div>
</div>

Aquí está el código corregido:
const fechaNacElements = document.querySelectorAll(".dateOfBirth"); // <---- corregido
const ageInputs = document.querySelectorAll(".age"); // <---- corregido

// Itera sobre cada elemento
for (let i = 0; i < fechaNacElements.length; i++) { // <---- corregido
    const fechaNacElement = fechaNacElements[i];
    let fechaNacText = fechaNacElement.textContent.trim();
    console.log("Fecha original:", fechaNacText);

    let partesFecha = fechaNacText.split(/[-/]/);
    let dateOfBirth;

    if (partesFecha.length === 3) {            
        if (partesFecha[0].length === 2) {
            dateOfBirth = new Date(partesFecha[2], partesFecha[1] - 1, partesFecha[0]);
        }            
        else {
            dateOfBirth = new Date(partesFecha[0], partesFecha[1] - 1, partesFecha[2]);
        }
    }

    console.log("Fecha parseada:", dateOfBirth); 

    if (dateOfBirth && !isNaN(dateOfBirth.getTime())) {
        calculateAge(dateOfBirth, ageInputs[i]); // <---- corregido
    } else {
        ageInputs[i].value = "Fecha inválida"; // <---- corregido
    }
}

function calculateAge(dateOfBirth, ageInput) { // <---- corregido
    const today = new Date();
    const ageInMilliseconds = today.getTime() - dateOfBirth.getTime();
    const ageInYears = Math.floor(ageInMilliseconds / 31536000000);
    const ageInMonths = Math.floor((ageInMilliseconds % 31536000000) / 2629800000);

    if (ageInYears === 0) {
        ageInput.value = ageInMonths === 0 ? `Días de nacido` :
            ageInMonths === 1 ? `${ageInMonths} mes` :
                `${ageInMonths} meses`;
    } else {
        const yearString = ageInYears === 1 ? `${ageInYears} año` : `${ageInYears} años`;
        const monthString = ageInMonths === 0 ? `` :
            ageInMonths === 1 ? ` y ${ageInMonths} mes` :
                ` y ${ageInMonths} meses`;
        ageInput.value = yearString + monthString;
    }
}

document.querySelectorAll permite la selección de varios elementos con la clase .dateOfBirth y .age.

